# PHP : strpos don't return result with apostrophe (')

Tags: php, strpos

I'm doing a small application that will parse a PDF file and return some content.

Here is a part of the content of the pdf file

> Nous publions ci-dessous par profession les candidat-e-s qui ont réussi l'examen partiel, l'examen de fin d'apprentissage, l'examen de maturité professionnelleou obtenu le titre par validation des acquis.Cette liste est complétée au fur et à mesure de la réception des résultats.Les candidat-e-s en situation d'échec sont avisé-e-s personnellement et ils/elles ne sont pas mentionné-e-s ci-dessous.AGENT-E D'EXPLOITATION CFCAGENT-E EN INFORMATION DOCUMENTAIRE CFCAIDE EN SOINS ET ACCOMPAGNEMENT AFP

There are job name (AGENT-E D'EXPLOITATION CFC, AGENT-E EN INFORMATION DOCUMENTAIRE CFC,...)

I've took all the jobs and made an array with them, something like 135 jobs. And then, I'd like to do a strpos() to get the starting position of the job. Problem, It didn't return me the job containing an apostrophe.

Here's a part of my code

```
echo "METIER 1 : " . strpos($texte, 'AGENT-E D\'EXPLOITATION CFC') . "</br>";
echo "METIER 1.2 : " . strpos($texte, "AGENT-E D'EXPLOITATION CFC") . "</br>";
echo "METIER 2 : " . strpos($texte, "AGENT-E EN INFORMATION DOCUMENTAIRE CFC") . "</br>";
```

And here is the result

> METIER 1 :
>
> METIER 1.2 :
>
> METIER 2 : 458

EDIT : Problem solved, the output from the pdf parser was corrupted, I just had to do a str_replace() and it's all good now !

Thank you everyone.

Comment: You should dump the text and copy the '. Some ' aren't the same as that on the English keyboard. Esp if you copied the text from web or pdf's, they often aren't the ' as you type on the English keyboard.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4793627fd02815c0dd5f5a43fa2f14ea7ca5856 works for me. Make sure you're actually getting single quotes and not some unicode equivalent that's not really a single quote in the ASCII sense

Comment: I've tried to do a var_dump($texte) and copy the '. Not working. Copy the ' from the original pdf, not working,putting the ' by hand, not working. I'm working with a swiss keyboard, using https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser for parsing the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the file_put_contents() to write the content of my $texte variable (the one coming out of the pdfparser) into a .txt file. After opening it, the problem was clear. It had replaced all the ' with an alphanumerical value.

I couldn't see the problem from firefox because it was interpreting this value and showed me a '.

I just had to do a str_replace() on my string and it's all good.

Thank you everyone for the help !

Answer (score 0):

This works, using a double quoted string instead of a single quouted string with escapes

```
echo "METIER 1 : " . strpos($texte, "AGENT-E D'EXPLOITATION CFC") . "</br>";
echo "METIER 1.2 : " . strpos($texte, "AGENT-E D'EXPLOITATION CFC") . "</br>";
echo "METIER 2 : " . strpos($texte, "AGENT-E EN INFORMATION DOCUMENTAIRE CFC") . "</br>";
```

Results

```
METIER 1 : 408
METIER 1.2 : 408
METIER 2 : 434
```

This also works for me

```
echo "METIER 1 : " . strpos($texte, 'AGENT-E D\'EXPLOITATION CFC') . PHP_EOL;
echo "METIER 1.2 : " . strpos($texte, "AGENT-E D'EXPLOITATION CFC") . PHP_EOL;
echo "METIER 2 : " . strpos($texte, "AGENT-E EN INFORMATION DOCUMENTAIRE CFC") . PHP_EOL;
```

Result

```
METIER 1 : 408
METIER 1.2 : 408
METIER 2 : 434
```

Comment: My exemple is not aligned well, but as you can see in METIER 1 and METIER 1.2, it's the same string but written with the 2 options.  EDIT : I see that it's working for you, could my php 7.0.6 create this problem ? Or is the string coming out of the pdf parser wrong ?

Comment: Maybe you have a minor corruption in your code file.

Comment: After testing by copy/pasting the content of $texte as it appears in firefox, it work's for me too, this must be a problem with the output from pdf parser.